# setDT() not working as expected, after loading a parquet file with open dataset

Tags: r

When I save a data.table as parquet file with write_parquet-function from arrow and then load it with open_dataset+collect functions, the loaded object (e.g. named d) is a data.table, but it doesn't work properly. For example if i try d[Tarif == "865", Tarifmerkmal := "?"]  i get the following error

Error in `[.data.table`(d, Tarif == "600", `:=`(Tarifmerkmal, "?")) :
ALTSTRING objects of type arrow::array_string_vector are immutable

I tried then to avoid this error with setDT(d), but the same error appeared. When i tried as.data.table(d)-> d2 instead of setDT, everything worked properly. Also when i tried setDT directly after collect, like this

open_dataset(sources = fileIntern) %>%
collect() %>% setDT() -> d

It also worked properly. But when i use setDT directly after collect it takes another 4 seconds to load, although the data is a data.table after collect. So i dont get why setDT doesn't work properly in the first case (open_dataset(sources = fileIntern) %>%
collect() -> d and afterwords setDT(d))
but work in the second case. Thanks in advance!